# How to set focus on textarea upon opening a component modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I'm trying to create a post creator like Facebook when you press on the text area it pops up another form with another Textarea I have already done that but the problem here that I can not set focus on the textarea in the new modal that pops up when I click on old textarea here is an image for a better explanation [image]

```
  <textarea class="form-control" placeholder="Write a post..." rows="3" v-model="post.Content"  :class="{ 'is-invalid': post.errors.has('Content') }" @click="postModal();setTextFocus()" @click.right="postModal();setTextFocus()"></textarea>

  <div class="modal-body"><!-- component modal -->
  <textarea class="form-control" v-bind:placeholder="'What is on your a mind, '+name+'?'" rows="3" v-model="post.Content"  :class="{ 'is-invalid': post.errors.has('Content') }" id="focusText" ref="textFocus"></textarea>
    <has-error  :form="post" field="Content"></has-error>
  </div>
methods:{
        postModal(){
            $('#postModal').modal('show');
            $("#myModal").on('shown.bs.modal', function(){
                $('#postModal').find('#focusText').focus();
            });

        },
        setTextFocus()
        {
            this.$refs.textFocus.focus();
        },
```

Edit I will add full code of my page

```js
<script>
    export default {
        //if you want to use the data in props in your axios request or add url parameters add them like this Axios.post('api/like',{id:this.post.id})
        props:['id','name'],
        data(){
            return{
                posts:{},
                userPhoto:'',
                page:1,
                post : new Form({
                    id:'',
                    Content:'',
                    user_id: this.id,
                })
            }
        },
        methods:{
            postModal() {
                $('#postModal').modal('show');
                $("#myModal").on('shown.bs.modal', function() {
                    $('#postModal').find('#focusText').focus();
                });

            },
            setTextFocus() {
                if ('textFocus' in this.$refs) {
                    this.$refs.textFocus.focus();
                }
            },
            //the problem was we used this.loadPosts in created so when the page load it requested data twice one from created and the other
            // one from infinite loading component SO you have to remove loadPosts methods from created() on rely on <infinity-loading> only
            loadPosts(page = this.page){
                Vue.axios.get('api/post?page='+page).then(({data})=>{
                    this.posts=data;
                    this.page=data.current_page;
                });
            },
            addPost(){
                this.$Progress.start();
                this.post.post('api/post').then(()=>{
                    $('#postModal').modal('hide');
                    this.post.reset();
                    Fire.$emit('loadPage');
                    Toast.fire({
                        icon: 'success',
                        title: 'Created successfully'
                    });
                    this.$Progress.finish();
                }).catch(()=>{
                    this.$Progress.fail();

                })
            },
            addLike(post_id){
                Vue.axios.post('api/like',{
                    post_id:post_id,
                    user_id:this.post.user_id,
                }).then(()=>{
                    Fire.$emit('loadPage');
                })
            },
            likedBythisUser(post){
                return post.likes.find(like=>{
                    return like.user_id===this.id && like.post_id===post.id;
                }) // return a boolean value
            },
            countComments(comments){
                const numberOfComments =comments.length;
                return numberOfComments;
            }

        },
        name: "Post",
        mounted() {
            this.setTextFocus()
        },

        created() {
            this.setTextFocus();
            Vue.axios.post('/user_photo').then((data)=>{
                this.userPhoto=data.data;
            });
            this.loadPosts();
            Fire.$on('loadPage',()=>{
                this.loadPosts();
            });

        },

    }
</script>
```

```css
<style scoped>
    .panel-shadow {
        box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3) 7px 7px 7px;
    }
    .panel-white {
        border: 1px solid #dddddd;
    }
    .panel-white  .panel-heading {
        color: #333;
        background-color: #fff;
        border-color: #ddd;
    }
    .panel-white  .panel-footer {
        background-color: #fff;
        border-color: #ddd;
    }

    .post .post-heading {
        height: 95px;
        padding: 20px 15px;
    }
    .post .post-heading .avatar {
        width: 60px;
        height: 60px;
        display: block;
        margin-right: 15px;
    }
    .post .post-heading .meta .title {
        margin-bottom: 0;
    }
    .post .post-heading .meta .title a {
        color: black;
    }
    .post .post-heading .meta .title a:hover {
        color: #aaaaaa;
    }
    .post .post-heading .meta .time {
        margin-top: 8px;
        color: #999;
    }
    .post .post-image .image {
        width: 100%;
        height: auto;
    }
    .post .post-description {
        padding: 15px;
    }
    .post .post-description p {
        font-size: 14px;
    }
    .post .post-description .stats {
        margin-top: 20px;
    }
    .post .post-description .stats .stat-item {
        display: inline-block;
        margin-right: 15px;
    }
    .post .post-description .stats .stat-item .icon {
        margin-right: 8px;
    }
    .post .post-footer {
        border-top: 1px solid #ddd;
        padding: 15px;
    }
    .post .post-footer .input-group-addon a {
        color: #454545;
    }
    .post .post-footer .comments-list {
        padding: 0;
        margin-top: 20px;
        list-style-type: none;
    }
    .post .post-footer .comments-list .comment {
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
        margin: 20px 0;
    }
    .post .post-footer .comments-list .comment .avatar {
        width: 35px;
        height: 35px;
    }
    .post .post-footer .comments-list .comment .comment-heading {
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
    }
    .post .post-footer .comments-list .comment .comment-heading .user {
        font-size: 14px;
        font-weight: bold;
        display: inline;
        margin-top: 0;
        margin-right: 10px;
    }
    .post .post-footer .comments-list .comment .comment-heading .time {
        font-size: 12px;
        color: #aaa;
        margin-top: 0;
        display: inline;
    }
    .post .post-footer .comments-list .comment .comment-body {
        margin-left: 50px;
    }
    .post .post-footer .comments-list .comment > .comments-list {
        margin-left: 50px;
    }
</style>
```

```html
<template>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-8"  >
            <div class="comment-wrapper">
                <div class="panel panel-info">
                    <form>
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <textarea class="form-control" placeholder="Write a post..." rows="3" v-model="post.Content"  :class="{ 'is-invalid': post.errors.has('Content') }" @click="setTextFocus(); postModal();"></textarea> <!-- here is the first textbox -->
                            <has-error  :form="post" field="Content"></has-error>
                            <br>
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info pull-right" @click.prevent="addPost()">Post</button>
                            <div class="clearfix"></div>
                            <hr>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="panel panel-white post panel-shadow" v-for="post in posts.data" >
                <div class="post-heading">
                    <div class="pull-left image">
                        <img v-bind:src="'img/profile/' + post.user.photo" class="img-circle avatar" alt="user profile image">
                    </div>

                    <div class="pull-left meta">
                        <i class="dropdown" style="margin-left:550px;position: relative;">
                            <button class="dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" style="background-color:#f8fafc; border: none">
                                ...
                            </button>
                            <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Edit post</a>
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Delete</a>
                            </div>
                        </i>
                        <div class="title h5">
                            <a href="#"><b>{{post.user.name}}  </b></a>
                            made a post.
                        </div>

                        <!-- | hour is called filter and we can stack many filters at the same time-->
                        <h6 class="text-muted time">{{post.created_at | hour}}</h6>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="post-description">
                    <p>{{post.content}}</p>
                    <div class="stats">
                        <button class="btn btn-default stat-item"  @click.prevent="addLike(post.id)">
                            <i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up" aria-hidden="false" style="color: blue" v-bind:style="likedBythisUser(post)?'color: blue;':'color: gray;'"  > Like &nbsp;{{post.likes.length}}
                            </i> 
                        </button>
                        <a class="btn btn-default stat-item" @click.prevent>
                            <i class="fa fa-reply-all" v-html="countComments(post.comments)"></i> Comments
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <comment-input :post="post" :userId="id" :userPhoto="userPhoto"></comment-input>
                <ul class="comments-list" v-for="comment in post.comments?post.comments:''">
                    <comments :comment="comment" :userId="id" :userPhoto="userPhoto"></comments>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <pagination :data="posts" @pagination-change-page="loadPosts"></pagination>
            <hr>
            <!-- Post Modal -->
            <div class="modal fade" id="postModal"  role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" style="margin-right: 100px">
                <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Create Post</h5>
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                            </button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            <textarea class="form-control" v-bind:placeholder="'What is on your a mind, '+name+'?'" rows="3" v-model="post.Content"  :class="{ 'is-invalid': post.errors.has('Content') }" id="focusText" ref="textFocus"></textarea> <!-- here is my second textarea i want it to appear inside my bootstrap modal -->
                            <has-error  :form="post" field="Content"></has-error>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info pull-right" @click.prevent="addPost()">Post</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

Comment: https://alligator.io/vuejs/component-lifecycle/  I would assume you would want an implementation of a `mounted` hook to set the focus, so that it executes once the component view has been created.

Comment: didn't work I edited the post with the full code page I hope it can help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

okay after searching for hours I found the solution to this problem, it was actually so simple I just had to check Modal bootstrap documentation, so here is the solution to save your time

```js
 methods:{
            postModal() {
                $('#postModal').modal('show');
                $('#postModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
                    $('#textFocus').trigger('focus')
                });
            },
            }
```

```html
<textarea class="form-control" placeholder="Write a post..." rows="3" v-model="post.Content"  :class="{ 'is-invalid': post.errors.has('Content') }" @click="postModal()" ></textarea>

<textarea class="form-control" v-bind:placeholder="'What is on your a mind, '+name+'?'" rows="3" v-model="post.Content"  :class="{ 'is-invalid': post.errors.has('Content') }"  id="textFocus" ref="textFocus"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 4):

The reason why your strategy didn't work is because chances are, `this.$refs.textFocus` does not yet exist in the DOM and therefore focusing it doesn't work.

You can focus on the textarea in the [`mounted` lifecycle hook](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#mounted) and after the [`$vm.nextTick()`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-nextTick) promise has been resolved, so that you're sure the element is indeed present in the DOM:

```
mounted() {
  this.$nextTick(() => this.$refs.textFocus.focus());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the function setTextFocus in the mounted hook.

```js
mounted() {
  this.setTextFocus()
},

methods: {
  postModal() {
    $('#postModal').modal('show');
    $("#myModal").on('shown.bs.modal', function() {
      $('#postModal').find('#focusText').focus();
    });

  },
  setTextFocus() {
    if ('textFocus' in this.$refs) {
        this.$refs.textFocus.focus();
    }
  },
}
```

```html
<textarea
  class="form-control"
  placeholder="Write a post..."
  rows="3"
  v-model="post.Content"
  :class="{ 'is-invalid': post.errors.has('Content') }"
  @click="postModal();setTextFocus()"
  @click.right="postModal();setTextFocus()">
 </textarea>

<div class="modal-body">
  <!-- component modal -->
  <textarea
    class="form-control"
    v-bind:placeholder="'What is on your a mind, '+name+'?'"
    rows="3"
    v-model="post.Content"
    :class="{ 'is-invalid': post.errors.has('Content') }"
    id="focusText"
    ref="textFocus">
   </textarea>
  <has-error :form="post" field="Content"></has-error>
</div>
```

Comment: i tried that and it didnt work I really don't understand why all i want when the modal show by using .modal('show') which is built in function the focus target by textarea in my modal .. i want to mention that I don't include the modal in a separate componant

Answer (score 1):

Try showing the modal using the `data` values

Set the status of modal to false as default

```
    data: () => {
        return {
            show: false
        }
    },
```

Then, use `v-show` to show/hide the modal (I removed some of the properties)

```
<div>
    <textarea class="form-control" placeholder="Write a post..." rows="3" @click="postModal()">
    </textarea>

    <div class="modal-body" v-show="show"><!-- component modal -->
        <textarea class="form-control" rows="3"
                  id="focusText"
                  ref="textFocus"></textarea>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now, inside the `postModal` method, set the `show` value to `true`

```
postModal: function () {
    this.show = true;
    setTimeout(() => {
        this.$refs.textFocus.focus(); // calling the focus after a timeout
    }, 0);
}
```

This is working for me.

Note:

- The timeout is requires because the `focus` should performed on clicking another `textarea`.
- The `0` in timeout means, running the code after relative process if any.
- I removed some of the properties to create a simple test code :).
- It is always better to keep the `JQuery` away from `Vue`

Comment: I cant toggle bootstrap modal using v-show I appreciate your help but didn't work for me.

Comment: Okay, got it. Can you try the timeout in my answer after `$('#postModal').modal('show');`?

Comment: yes I tried that too but didn't work, well anyway i found the solution for my problem you can check my answer, thanks for your support :)

Answer (score 0):

Simply use, `<textarea autofocus placeholder="Write a post..."></textarea>`